# How to call other python script in another python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to call other python script to another python script using import but it is giving some error. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

`case.py` is my one script which have one one function `generate_case('rule_id')`. This function is returning some value.

`final.py` is my another script in which I am trying to call above script and store return value into a variable.

I am trying to do in python :

```
import case as f_case

qry = ''
qry += f_case.generate_case('R162')
print(qry)
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'case'
```

Both the scripts are available in the same location.

Comment: In which directory are the both files placed?

Comment: @HarishankarG both the scripts are in same place

Comment: I do not think they are in the same location, or there is some other info missing ... what you did should absolutely work fine ... at the top add `import os;print(os.getcwd());print(os.listdir("."))`  (see also : https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/UnrealisticLegalQuotes#main.py)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Scripts are in same place.

Comment: then you are leaving out other critical details ... that no one can answer without ... try it in a vacuum and then expand upon you basic truth that this should totally work

Comment: @JoranBeasley Can you please help what am missing?

Comment: i have no idea ... if you have only those two scripts with only that code it works exactly as you expect ... start a new project or folder and put only those two scripts in ... start adding the rest of your scripts running it regularly until it breaks... whatever script you added right before it breaks is probably the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
import sys

scriptpath=''
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))

# Do the import
import case as f_case
```

Answer (score 0):

I rename the script as `new_cons.py`. Now it working for me. May be in script name I have added integer so it is not importing the script.